# "Dead Store" warning XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I am getting a dead store warning when I analyze my project but the project does not crash.
"Value stored to 'row' during its initialization is never read".
Here is what I am doing:

```
long row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row; // there is dead store warning
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_pdd_ab_stat) == SQLITE_OK) {
    for (row = 0; row < 40; row ++) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Max(rightCount) from paper_ab_stat WHERE biletNumber = \"%ld\"", row + 1];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_pdd_ab_stat, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSNumber *arrayelement = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)];
                [_biletRecords addObject:arrayelement];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}
sqlite3_close(_pdd_ab_stat);

return _biletRecords;
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you aren't using the value before it's reassigned to `0` in the `for` loop:

```
long row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_pdd_ab_stat) == SQLITE_OK) {
    for (row = 0; row < 40; row ++) {   // Reassigned!
```

To fix:

```
long row;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_pdd_ab_stat) == SQLITE_OK) {
    for (row = 0; row < 40; row ++) {
```

(although that looks broken; you probably want to use a different variable in the `for` loop).

Comment: thanks, fixed with delete first line and with editing loop as for (long row = 0; row < 40; row ++) {
it was my stupid fail :)